# Open source data for bitcoin Blockchain analysis

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to find money laundering and other 'bad' use cases of the bitcoin. Of course, the public Blockchain is available to me and that is my main data source. But this is also quite limiting because all I can do is run 'pattern recognition' like algorithm.

I can test, supervise and improve my performance if I can have access to previous analyses on the blockchain regarding financial activities. For instance, a set of tagged Bitcoin addresses, a network of organizations within the Blockchain, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help but there does seem a set of transactions tagged as silkroad seized bitcoins on the blockchain explorer. Silkroad was notorious for a while as an underground marketplace for drugs and other illegal activities:
[Silkroad seized bitcoins](https://blockchain.info/address/1F1tAaz5x1HUXrCNLbtMDqcw6o5GNn4xqX)